# How do we do spatial queries in Cassandra? Is there any GIS extension for Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, bigdata, gis, geospatial

I need a GIS extension in cassandra extension to capture, store, manipulate, analyze, manage, and present all types of geographical data.

Something like PostGIS for PostgreSQL. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

[GeoMesa project](https://www.geomesa.org/) has support for Cassandra as a storage, but it's performance may not be very optimal because of data model & queries.